# Combine model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I combine my tables to `Result`. İt works with no problem.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var Result = new Modeller
  {
    KISALTMALAR = context.KISALTMALAR.ToList(),
    FirmaListesiGetir = context.SP_FIRMA_LISTESI_GETIR().ToList(),
  };
  return View(Result );
}
```

However, when using multiple actions, i have to write the above code every time.

For instance:

```
public ActionResult Customer()
{
  var Result = new Modeller
  {
    KISALTMALAR = context.KISALTMALAR.ToList(),
    FirmaListesiGetir = context.SP_FIRMA_LISTESI_GETIR().ToList(),
  };
  return View(Result );
}

public ActionResult Product()
{
  var Result = new Modeller
  {
    KISALTMALAR = context.KISALTMALAR.ToList(),
    FirmaListesiGetir = context.SP_FIRMA_LISTESI_GETIR().ToList(),
  };
return View(Result );
}
```

İ have to combine my tables in every actionresult.

How can i write **only one time** and **use** my `Result` **everywhere** ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just reference a shared class/service. For example:

```
public class YourService
{
    public static Modeller GetCombinedTables()
    {
         return new Modeller
                    {
                        KISALTMALAR = context.KISALTMALAR.ToList(),
                        FirmaListesiGetir = context.SP_FIRMA_LISTESI_GETIR().ToList()
                    };
    }
}
```

Then, in your action you can just call that method:

```
public ActionResult Customer()
{
    var Result = YourService.GetCombinedTables();
    return View(Result);
}
```

You can also create the `Result` variable at controller level, so that way you don't have to assign it for every action.

Comment: An object reference is is required  for non static field for this code 

var Result = YourService.GetCombinedTables(); , i miss somewhere too..

Comment: Missed the static keyword.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows. I always use this approach:

```
public Modeller GetResult()
{
   var result = new Modeller
  {
    KISALTMALAR = context.KISALTMALAR.ToList(),
    FirmaListesiGetir = context.SP_FIRMA_LISTESI_GETIR().ToList(),
  };

  return result;
}


public ActionResult Customer()
{
  var Result = GetResult();
  return View(Result);
}

public ActionResult Product()
{
  var Result = GetResult();
  return View(Result);
```

}